# python : file synchronous R/W & multiprocessing

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to design a program in python that can share the json file with a server all the time, so I tested to determine whether there an issue when reading and writing the file. ***The reading of the file has a gap between the changes of content of the file.***

#### Separate files

Here is my codes:

```
#write.py

#from time import sleep

i = 0

while 1:
    f = open("test.txt", 'w')
    f.write(str(i))
    f.close()
    i+=1
#    sleep(1)
```

And

```
#read.py
#import time

f = open("test.txt", 'r')

while 1:
    print "::> ", f.read()
#    time.sleep(1)
    f.seek(0,0)
```

Executed in separate terminal:

```
bash4.2$ python read.py >> logfile.log

bash4.2$ python write.py
```

I log the output of read.py and get this result:

```
::>  1
::>  1
::>  1
::>  1
::>  1
::>  1
::>  1
::>  
::>  
::>  
::>  
::>  2
::>  2
::>  2
::>  2
```

[Here is the image of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFoyt.png)

#### Tried with multiprocessing:

```
#rw.py
import multiprocessing as m


def writing():
    i = 0
    while 1:
        fw = open("test.txt", 'w')
        fw.write(str(i))
        fw.close()
        i+=1

def reading():
    fr = open("test.txt", 'r')
    while 1:
        print "::> ", fr.read()
        fr.seek(0,0)

def main():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p_w = m.Process(target=writing, args=())
        p_r = m.Process(target=reading, args=())

        p_w.start()
        p_r.start()

        p_w.join()
        p_r.join()

main()
```

Execute in Terminal:

```
bash4.2$ python rw.py >> logfile.log
```

I log the output of this:

```
::>  0
::>  0
::>  0
::>  0
::>  
::>  1
::>  1
::>  1
```

[This is the picture of result of multiprocessing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nCW6.png)

**It can be observed that there is always a gap between the change of number. The file using *multiprocessing* generates only one line gap.**

Why does that happen? How could I avoid it?
If it could be avoided, how does the solution applied to the interaction between the server and python program?

Thanks.

***########Update 1########***

I have tested the program many times and tried with C and Python with the same process. I found that the write and read are not very synchronous in both operating system and software stages. **(i.e. The log shows that the gaps between different numbers are different)**

It appears to be that there is a priority problem with multiprocessing. Sometimes the log starts from a very big and unreasonable number.

***########Update 2########***

I success to call the priority within multiprocessing to gain the file I/O synchronous.

```
from multiprocessing import *

def writer(queue):
        i = 0
        while 1:
                f = open("test.txt", 'w')
                f.write(str(i))
                queue.put("ready")
                i+=1
                f.close()
                queue.put("end")

def reader(queue):
        f = open("test.txt",'r')
        for temp in iter(queue.get, "ready"):
                pass
        while 1:
                for judge in iter(queue.get, "end"):
                        f.seek(0,0)
                        print f.read()

def main():
        if __name__ == '__main__':
                queue = Queue()

                reader_p = Process(target=reader, args=(queue,))
                reader_p.daemon = True
                reader_p.start()

                writer_p = Process(target=writer, args=(queue,))
                writer_p.daemon = True
                writer_p.start()

                reader_p.join()
                writer_p.join()
main()
```

However, this starts from 1 in log file.
It seems that file is empty before the write function is called. The shift of asynchronous processes make the processes are called within a fixed period of time. But from previous results, it showed that the timing is not perfect since two processes have unconnected period.

So why is that?

Comment: When you signed up, you were encouraged to take the SO tour and study the Help section.In your case I suggest reading #1 of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have written the json file operation, I have found that the data will not be updated well when time.sleep() is called in not all the functions. It seems that the timing synchronous (not only hardware) even in software is also important. But what is the concept behind this?

Comment: @MrT thanks for the guideline, I am new here. And now I make the question clear.